# Relative Layout View Alignments

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

[image]

The image above has many problems starting with the icon is not top aligning with the image. Also, I'd love to have UserName centered with respect to the icon.

Finally, I want to have the last line aligned with the bottom of the Image to the left.

I started using layout_weight and i couldn't get it to work. So, I applied hard widths and heights.

Ideally, I would like to have the first ImageView occupy 30% of the row. The Icon would occupy 7% and the rest will be allocated to the textview on first row.

Thanks for your suggestions.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_shape"
                >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgVideo"
        android:src="@drawable/video_default_preview"
        android:layout_width = "150dp"
        android:layout_height= "150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgOwner"
        android:layout_width = "35dp"
        android:layout_height= "35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_default_avator"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgVideo"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgVideo"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Plus"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgOwner"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVideoTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mercedes SL 55"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgOwner"
        android:layout_below="@id/imgOwner"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVideoName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="European Car ..."
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtVideoTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtVideoTitle"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your xml as you described.

> Ideally, I would like to have the first ImageView occupy 30% of the
>   row. The Icon would occupy 7% and the rest will be allocated to the
>   textview on first row.

To do this you should use linearlayouts which has weight attr. (30% for first image, 70% for others. And 7% of 70%'s which is equal to %10 inside for the icon)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgVideo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgOwner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtVideoTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:text="Mercedes SL 55"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtVideoName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="European Car ..."
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Plus" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Plus"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Mercedes SL 55"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="European Car ..."/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```